Can I mark a group of QGIS layer to only load into a project when selected?
I have a project where I have several versions of a drawing as the project progresses and is redesigned over time.
I used the DXF Import/Convert plugin as the best way to load these from Autocad without errors.
The drawing has about 60 Autocad layers, and they are loaded by duplicating the drawing and filtering by layer name, and saving all these qgis layers in a group with the drawing name.
When it starts each layer seems to take 0.1 sec to add to the project, but by the time I get to my 700th layer it grows exponentially, they are taking 25s a time to add in, such that my project now takes over an hour to load.
99% of the time, I just want to use the current drawing status, but occasionally I want to compare and refer to one of the earlier design stages.
Is there any way I can mark these groups of layers such that they will only load if selected? Or some similar workaround?  - It is very convenient the way it works once loaded, and I would rather not delete the old progress versions if I could keep them in the project, and only take a hit if I chose to include them later on.
However, another update or two would render the whole thing completely unviable.

You might save earlier versions as layer files (qlr) and add those only when needed.
